# How can I enable spell checking in Vim only for SpellBad and disable the rest (SpellCap, SpellRare, and SpellLocal)?

Tags: vim

I know that I can enable spell checking in Vim with `:set spell`. But is there a way to only enable SpellBad and disable the rest (SpellCap, SpellRare, and SpellLocal)? I know that I can change the highlight of the unwanted checks ( like `:hi SpellLocal gui=NONE term=NONE` ) so that they don't show up, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you find anything in `:help spell`?

Comment: I can disable SpellCap with `set spellcapcheck=`. And I can disable SpellLocal by combining all the locales with `set spelllang=en_us,en_gb,en_au,en_ca,en_nz`. As for SpellRare, I have found no way to disable it other than to modify the spellfiles.

Comment: There you have your answer.